# django how to find the minimum value NOT in a field?

Tags: django, python-3.x, database, django-models, orm

Assume that we have records with 1,2,4,5,6, ... in a field named Code in table Material. How can I write an orm to return 3 that is the minimum number not in the existing records?

Comment: Why is the number not `0`? It does not make much sense to do that, since a database basically uses the "closed world assumption".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using a subquery

```
all_codes = Material.objects.values('Code')

Material.objects.annotate(
    next=F('Code') + 1
).exclude(
    next__in=all_codes
).aggregate(
    minimum_code=Min('next')
)['minimum_code']
```

We find all rows where the next number after Code is not in all values for Code and the minimum value for this annotation is the lowest number not existing in the table

This table hopefully illustrates what is going on

```
|------|------|--------------------|
| Code | next | next in all Codes? |
|------|------|--------------------|
|   1  |   2  |        True        |
|------|------|--------------------|
|   2  |   3  |        False       |  <- The minimum next not in all codes
|------|------|--------------------|
|   4  |   5  |        True        |
|------|------|--------------------|
|   5  |   6  |        True        |
|------|------|--------------------|
|   6  |   7  |        False       |
|------|------|--------------------|
```

Bear in mind, if you are using MySQL it is **terrible** at handling subqueries. In this case it is sometimes faster to evaluate the subquery first and then pass the result as a list (if the result is not too large) `next__in=list(Material.objects.values_list('Code', flat=True))`

This will only give the correct result if the minimum value is not lower than all existing values, you should check for this case first

```
minimum_code = Material.objects.aggregate(minimum_code=Min('Code'))['minimum_code']
if minimum_code > 1:  # Or whatever default value you want
    return 1
else:
    # Do the above
```